# How to create an instance of Gitblit in my java program

Tags: instantiation, gitblit

I need to call some git functions from my program. I am getting `NPE` and may be I am not properly instantiating the class.

```
GitBlit gitblit = new GitBlit();
gitblit.getRepositoryList();
```

Is this the wrong way?

Even I tried with `GitBlit.self().getRepositoryList();` and still the output was an `NPE`. 
I have a gitblit server running my local machine as `https://milestones.af.com:8443`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer from James Moger to the same question asked in the [GitBlit forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gitblit/M0TiQpETFgY):

> HI Manisha,
>
> In the 1.3.x code GitBlit is the context for the webapp.  It is a
>   singleton but it must be properly initialized by the container through
>   web.xml or by using the embedded Jetty.  In the 1.3.x code you can't
>   just instantiate a GitBlit instance and have it be ready for use.
>
> In the current master branch (1.4.x) things have been massively
>   refactored and modularized.  GitBlit is no longer a webapp context but
>   is the aggregation of several smaller classes.  It still relies on
>   proper initialization/configuration but this requirement is now more
>   obvious.
>
> Depending on your needs, you may do better with just harvesting code
>   from the JGitUtils class.
>
> -J